# What's the term for the person of whom a dependent is a dependent?

Tags: meaning

Alternately (but less precisely) asked, what's the term for the person upon whom a dependent depends?

I'm working specifically in a medical benefits context, but I'm not necessarily looking for a legal or policy term. I'm hoping there's a generic term for "the person through whom a dependent receives benefits." It's just so cumbersome otherwise...

Antecedent doesn't seem quite right... Nor does "supporter."

Dependee?

Comment: It depends on the context.  The most generic terms I can think of are "provider" and "benefactor."

Comment: Do you mean to use *dependant* in the normal sense of the word? As stated in another comment, the opposite of the *beneficiary* of a medical plan is a *benefactor*. But the opposite of a *dependant* would be a *guardian*.

Comment: I think some combined use of _benefactor_ and _guardian_ is really the most appropriate.

Comment: isn’t that the ***primary insured***?

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of [an earlier question](/q/36033). What is different about this one?

Comment: Yeah, that's a good candidate for primacy.

Answer (score 0):

"Sponsor" is used in the military. "Primary member" could work for the family member upon whom the dependent is dependent.

"Provider" in insurance usage is the one performing some service, so don't confuse this term with employee.

Answer (score 0):

"I'm working specifically in a medical benefits context" -- so the correct answer is to ask your employer. For example in the British NHS (National Health Service), there is an entire "data dictionary" of these things, defined in very formal terms (one example item: PATIENT: [https://www.datadictionary.nhs.uk/classes/patient.html])

Your employer either has a similar dictionary, or can refer you to the correct person. Random Internet folks probably cannot (although "benefactor", as suggested, seems pretty solid).

Comment: Normally, I would agree, but given that I am the one establishing such terminology for our team, I don't have that kind of reference to use (though I could refer to the rest of the industry). Consequently, I'd like to select the most appropriate English word.